Tag [command] vs. [user-commands] confusion
I found an inconsistency in our tags and am unsure how to handle it.
We do have the following two tags (with respective usage guidance and number of questions):

command Question about the command functionality that les the user define new Vim commands. - 94 questions
user-commmands Questions about :command and how the user can define custom commands. - 34 questions

Okay, one is about :command which creates a user-defined command and the other one is about user-defined commands and how they are created. Two ways to describe the same thing, obviously.
What makes this tricky is that - I did not go through all 94 questions - but it seems a fair share of them is using command incorrectly.
It expresses that there's an Ex command involved somewhere in the question.
This, by the way, is how I'd have understood command as well.
Are command and user-command really the same or should they be disambiguated?

If yes: which tag to keep? I found Do we have a tag for user defined commands questions? where command was suggested but user-commands was agreed on.

If no: Do we want to have command at all or is it something so basic that we don't need it?



For Ex commands, I'd have expected ex or a command-specific tag, maybe? Also, general confusion arises from the fact that some folks call Normal mode Command mode. Then there's the "just because it's in the question doesn't mean it needs a tag"—tags should be things folks can be experts in, ostensibly

Technically, normal mode commands are "commands" as well which would include commands like / or i. I did miss that last night but, yes, there's [ex-command] as well. Its info is something about the history of ex (I don't get how that would be helpful) but that's easily improved.

As suggested by D. Ben Knoble in his comment: burninate command as it adds no useful information to a post.
Go through all questions and retag them as either ex-command or user-commands - or just remove it, if it's not essential to the question.

The tag user-commands is to the point while command is easily misunderstood.
I'd prefer to have two tags:

user-commands keep as-is for questions related to user-defined commands.
command for questions about Ex commands, in general. This seems a bit verbose as everything in Vim is a command but people are using it. There's a demand.

This means we'll have to change the tag's usage guidance and then go through all questions tagged command and ...

retag to user-commands if that was meant
not touch anything if it's about command usage (should be true for several if not most questions)


I think command might just need to go—I'm not sure what useful information it provides to an answerer (or question-asker, frankly)

@D.BenKnoble good point. I wrote another answer to that effect to allow the community to vote. Feel free to edit or write a better answer of your own (I'd delete my answer in that case).

What you wrote looks great to me
